# Can't get authorization plugin to work with Solr JWTAuthPlugin

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have secured Solr (8.7.0) using JWTAuthTPlugin so I can use AAD from auth. I want to whitelist healthcheck metrics. I get 401 on all whitelisted request. I can login on Solr Admin using AAD

here's my security.json

```
{
  "authentication": {
    "class": "solr.JWTAuthPlugin",
    "blockUnknown": false,
    "wellKnownUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenant/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    "clientId": "myClientId",
    "adminUiScope": "openid api://myAPIid/solr"
  },
  "authorization":{
    "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "permissions":[ {
      "collection": null,
      "name": "healthcheckv2",
      "path": "/api/node/health",
      "role": null
    }, {
      "collection": null,
      "name": "healthcheckv1",
      "path": "/solr/admin/info/health",
      "role": null
    }, {
      "collection": null,
      "name": "infosystem",
      "path": "/solr/admin/info/system",
      "role": null
    }, {
      "collection": null,
      "name": "metrics",
      "path": "/admin/metrics",
      "role": null
    }, {
      "name": "security-edit",
      "role": "admin"
    }, {
      "name": "collection-admin-edit",
      "role": "admin"
    }, {
      "name": "core-admin-edit",
      "role": "admin"
    }, {
      "name": "all",
      "role": "*"
    }],
    "user-role": {
      "solr": "admin"
    }   
  }
}
```

What I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After debugging Solr, seems that a RuleContainer rewrote the path to health check :

2021-06-14 18:19:52.941 DEBUG (qtp1581267786-21) [   ] o.e.j.r.h.RuleContainer rewrote /api/node/health to /solr/____v2/node/health

so we need to adjust the permission accordingly:

```
 {
      "collection": null,
      "name": "healthcheckv2Rewrite",
      "path": "/____v2/node/health",
      "role": null
    }
```